# Json get attribute from array?

Tags: json, ajax, jsonp

I have json array,  please help me get price from this array

```
 {  
           "RAW":{  
              "BTC":{  
                 "USD":{  
                    "TYPE":"5",
                    "FROMSYMBOL":"BTC",
                    "TOSYMBOL":"USD",
                    "FLAGS":"2",
                    "PRICE":1082.13,
                    "LASTUPDATE":1483529467,
                    "LASTVOLUME":2.31159402,
                    "LASTVOLUMETO":2496.5215415999996,
                    "LASTTRADEID":12826318,
                    "VOLUME24HOUR":72040.63471484324,
                    "VOLUME24HOURTO":75043516.07861365,
                    "OPEN24HOUR":1020.95,
                    "HIGH24HOUR":1097.54,
                    "LOW24HOUR":980,
                    }
```

I write this code, but it don't work, where is mistake

```
    function getRate() {
            $.getJSON("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms=BTC&tsyms=USD")
            .done(function (data) {
                if (data) {
                    $('.price').html(data.PRICE)
                }
            });
        }

            getRate();
```

Tnx for answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
data.RAW.BTC.USD.PRICE
```

Your function will

```
function getRate() {
        $.getJSON("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms=BTC&tsyms=USD")
            .done(function (data) {
                if (data) {
                    $('.price').html(data.RAW.BTC.USD.PRICE)
                }
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's `data.RAW.BTC.USD.PRICE`, you can inspect this by using `console.log(data);` within the done() function.